# Using a regular expression to validate email addresses

Tags: php, regex

I have just started learning to code both PHP as well as HTML and had a look at a few tutorials on regular expressions however have a hard time understanding what these mean. I appreciate any help.

For example, I would like to validate the email address peanuts@monkey.com. I start off with the code and I get the message invalid email address.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. I know that the metacharacters such as ^ denote the start of a string and $ denote the end of a string however what does this mean? What is the start of a string and what is the end of a string?
3. When do I group regular expressions?

```
$emailaddress = 'peanuts@monkey.com';

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-z0-9]+@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]$/', $emailaddress)) {
    echo 'Great, you have a valid email address';       
} else {
    echo 'boo hoo, you have an invalid email address';      
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a tool such as http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to help understand and craft regular expressions

Comment: Rather than specifying `A-Za-z`, make the regex case-insensitive with the `/i` modifier.

Comment: What about: `John.Smith@gmail.com` thats a valid e-mail that fails your test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have written works with some small modifications if that is what you want to use, however you miss a '+' at the end.

1)

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

2. 

The caret and dollar character match positions rather than characters, ^ is equal to the beginning of line and $ is equal to the end of line, they are used to anchor your regex. If you write your regex without those two you will match email addresses everywhere in your text, not only the email addresses which is on a single line in this case. If you had written only the ^ (caret) you would have found every email address which is on the start of the line and if you had written only the $ (dollar) you would have found only the email addresses on the end of the line.

> Blah blah blah someEmail@email.com
> blah blah

would not give you a match because you do NOT have a email address at the beginning of line and the line does not terminate with it either so in order to match it in this context you would have to drop ^ and $.

3. Grouping is used for two reasons as far I know: Back referencing and... grouping. Grouping is used for the same reasons as in math, 1 + 3 * 4 is not the same as (1 + 3) * 4. You use parentheses to constrain quantifiers such as '+', '*' and '?' as well as alternation '|' etc.

You also parentheses for back referencing, but since I can't explain it better I would link you to: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

I will encourage you to take a look at this book, even though you only read the first 2-3 chapters you will learn a lot and it is a great book! http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570

---

And as the commentators say, this regex is not perfect but it works and show you what you had forgotten. You were not far away!

---

**UPDATED as requested:**

The '+', '*' and '?' are quantifiers. And is also a good example where you group.

- '+' mean match whatever charachter preceeds it or group 1 or n times.
- '*' mean match whatever charachter preceeds it 0 or n times.
- '?' mean match whatever charachter preceeds it or the group 0 or 1 time.

*n times meaning (indefinitely)*

The reason why you use [a-zA-Z0-9]+ is without the '+' it will only match one character. With the + it will match many but it must match at least one. With * it match many but also 0, and ? will match 1 character at most but also 0.

Comment: This is the correct answer :) Just answer 2) and 3) and you're done!

Comment: Codemonkey's suggested regex is way better than this one!

Comment: @Bodgan Agree, but this changes completely the logic of the OP's regex. There are **lots** of regex for validating emails, but I don't think that is the idea. The OP was asking: **What am I doing wrong?**. I think he prefers learning Regular Expressions than just validating an email address.

Comment: well said @Oscar - @Codemonkey's regex is much better, but still not good. It is very difficult to match an email address, especially as the specification changes over time, and there are some very strange use cases - like `+` signs in gmail addresses used for filtering for example. Generally I think validation is over-used and does not help anyone. It does not validate that the email exists - only that it could exist at best - and even then, I have never seen a watertight regex to do that.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. I still don't follow what you meant by the start of the line and the end of the line. For example I have a single line that reads This is my email address peanuts@monkey.com. This is also my email address monkey@peanuts.com. So is the start and end of the line as follows [start] This is my email address peanuts@monkey.com. This is also my email address monkey@peanuts.com [end]?

Comment: @Bogdan Constantinescu - I am in no position to state which code is better as I am learning however I am keen to know what was wrong with what the code I came up with so that I can learn regular expressions. I am not looking to just copy and paste code.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Yes, that is correct. [start]...text...[end] They match the position.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: I've edited in why your expression didn't work in my answer :)

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. Why is that Codemonkey states it wouldn't work in the example My email address is peanuts@monkey.com, and I love it!

Also what does the + symbol do exactly?

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. Sorry I still don't get it. I have the line "This is my email address peanuts@monkey.com. This is also my email address monkey@peanuts.com" which I take would read "[start] This is my email address peanuts@monkey.com. This is also my email address monkey@peanuts.com [end]". 

However my validation fails. It returns invalid email address although the email addresses are in the same line. What am I missing to understand?

Comment: @Peanut Updated answer, which regex are you using?

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. I am so sorry. I don't follow the following examples

+' mean match whatever charachter preceeds it or group 1 or n times.
'*' mean match whatever charachter preceeds it 0 or n times.
'?' mean match whatever charachter preceeds it or the group 0 or 1 time.

when you say precede, what does that mean exactly? Are you able to give me examples?

Comment: @Andreas - What do you mean which regex I am using? I updated my code as follows - `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`

Comment: I think reading a thorough tutorial is what you need. If you read through [this tutorial](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html) and check out the examples, this comment thread will likely be redundant.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey That regular expression don't work because you have to remove ^ and $. In this case you want to match email address that also is not at the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: @Codemonkey - Thanks I was reading the example about the symbols ^ and $ and it make sense in the example because they were in 2 separate lines however in my example where I have the email address in the same line i.e. peanuts@monkey.com is my email as is monkey@penauts.com and my regex fails?

Comment: Okay. I think I get it. Sorry for being such a noob. I tried the following variations with the regex and my results are as follows. Please correct me if I am wrong

Regex - /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/

Variation 1 - $emailaddress = 'peanuts@monkey.com is my email as is monkey@penauts.com';
False

Regex - /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/

Variation 2 - $emailaddress = 'peanuts@monkey.com is my email';
True

Regex - /[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/

Variation 2 - $emailaddress = 'my email as is monkey@penauts.com';
True

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I will strongly suggest to read the linked tutorial that CodeMonkey or read the first chapters in the book I gave a link to if you don't understand it yet. Because I am not able to give you a better answer now, I am sorry.

Comment: So that would mean the email address would have to be at the start of the string or the end if I use ^ $. If I wanted to match an email address in the middle of the string I should not use the ^ and $ symbols. Hopefully I have understood it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Yes that is correct, however that will only give true values when the email address is on the end of the line. If you combine both ^ and $ the mail address need to be on its own line. ^ means that the email needs to be on the start of the line and $ is that the email address needs to be on the end of line.

Comment: @Andreas - I take it when you mean the regex is /[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/. That would match only when the email address is at the end of the line.

Comment: @Andreas - When you say I combine them, I take you mean that the string can only have email address and nothing else

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey At that line yes. However you could have a longer text but the email address needs to be on its own line in that case.

Comment: @Andreas - So just to be very clear for my own sake

Line 1 - Some text
Line 2 - email address - True

Line 1 - Some text email address - False

if we use the regex /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.

Comment: @Andreas: What you're saying is only true if the `Global` and `Multiline` flags are set. Otherwise `^` and `$` means the start and end of the string respectively, not the line. (The `Global` flag allows for several matches in one string which I assume as necessary to match multiple lines)

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: If all you're after is to check if a string contains an email address, just use `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/`. So far I have assumed that you wanted to check if a string **is** an email address, not just contains one.

Comment: @Codemonkey - I understand that the regex sample you just provided means that no matter where in the single line of string I have, I will find the email address. However if I include `^` and `$`, it would mean that the string can only have an email address.

Comment: It would mean that the string must consist of only the email address, yes. If even a single white-space character exists before or after the address, the string wouldn't get matched by the regular expression.

Comment: Great. Think I have finally understood it. Thanks for your patience for a noob. Getting there slowly but surely as they say.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex doesn't match email addresses. Try this one:

```
/\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/
```

I recommend you read through [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to learn about Regular Expressions.

Also, [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is great for testing them out.

As for your second question; the `^` character means that the regular expression must start matching from the first character in the string you input. The `$` means that the regular expression must end at the final character in the string you input. In essence, this means that your regular expression will match the following string:

> peanuts@monkey.com

but NOT the following string:

> My email address is peanuts@monkey.com, and I love it!

Grouping regular expressions has lots of use cases. Using matching groups will also make your expression cleaner and more readable. It's all explained quite well in the tutorial I linked earlier.

---

As CanSpice points out, matching all possible email addresses isn't all that easy. Using the RFC2822 Email Validation expression will do a better job:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

There are many alternatives, but even the simplest ones will do a fair job as most email addresses end in .com (or other 2-4 character length top domains).

---

The only reason your original expression doesn't work is that you're limiting the number of characters behind the period (.) in your expressions to 1. Changing your expression to:

```
/^[a-zA-z0-9]+@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]+$/
```

Will allow for an infinite amount of characters behind the last period.

```
/^[a-zA-z0-9]+@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/
```

Will allow 2 to 4 characters behind the last period. That would match:

> name@email.com
>
> name@email.info

but not:

> fake@address.suckers

Comment: That regex doesn't match all email addresses either.

Comment: Thanks. I am still stumbling to understand why My email address is peanuts@monkey.com, and I love it! would not work if they are in/on the same line.

Comment: Because `^p` means that the beginning of the string input MUST be the letter **p**. Similarly, `p$` means that the input string MUST end with the letter **p**. In other words, putting `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of an expression, respectively, means that the expression MUST match the entire input string. So "email@address.com" will be matched successfully, but "My address is email@address.com!" will not, because the string contains MORE than just the address. Do you understand now? :)

Answer (score 1):

The top level domain (".com," ".net," ".museum") can be from 2 to 6 characters.  So you should be saying 2,6 instead of 2,4.

I wrote an extremely good email address regular expression a few years ago:

^\w+([-+._]\w+)*@(\w+((-+)|.))*\w{1,63}.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$

A lot of research went into that.  But I have some basic tips:

DON'T JUST COPY-PASTE!  If someone says "here's a great regex for that," don't just copy paste it!  Understand what's going on!  Regular expressions are not that hard.  And once you learn them well, it'll pay dividends forever.  I got good at them by taking a class in Perl back in college.  Since then, I've barely gotten any better and am WAY better than the vast majority of programmers I know.  It's sad.  Anyways, learn it!

Start small.  Instead of building a giant regex and testing it when you're done, test just a few characters.  For example, when writing an email validator, why not try \w+@\w+.\w+ and see how good that is?  Add in a few more things and re-test.  Like ^\w+@\w+.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$

Answer (score 0):

The start and end of a regex string means that nothing can come before or after the characters you specify. Your regex string needs to account for underscores, needs capitals Zs with your capital ranges, and other adjustments.

```
/^[a-zA-Z_0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/
```

`{2,4}` says the top level domain is between 2 and 4 characters.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. Sorry, I don't follow what you mean by the start and end of a string. As my commet to Oscar Mederos does it mean start] This is my email address peanuts@monkey.com. This is also my email address monkey@peanuts.com [end] assuming that they are on the same line?

Comment: If I said '\d{1}' instead of '^\d{1}$', then it would accept a digit plus anything before or after the digit. The latter makes sure you get only the one digit (nothing before or after it).

Answer (score 0):

This will validate ANY email address (at least i've tried a lot )

`preg_match("/^[a-z0-9._-]{2,}+\@[a-z0-9_-]{2,}+\.([a-z0-9-]{2,4}|[a-z0-9-]{2,}+\.[a-z0-9-]{2,4})$/i", $emailaddress);`

Hope it works!

Comment: Doesn't match `üñîçøðé@travel` for example. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you ALWAYS escape metacharacters (like dot):

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-z0-9]+@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]$/', $emailaddress)) {
```

Comment: yeap, I forgot things that our friends already have meantioned; like plus after last list [a-zA-z0-9]+