# How can I verify an email address in PHP?

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Is there a PHP library for email address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)

How can I verify an email address in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737290/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-email-addresses

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if an email address exists, check out [checkdnsrr](http://php.net/checkdnsrr):

```
if (checkdnsrr('you@user.com', 'MX')) {
    echo ':)';
}
else {
   echo ':(';
}
```

If you want to check if a string is an email address, there are literally millions of regulars expressions out there. There's a native function in php, [filter_input](http://php.net/filter-input) that does it, thought I've personally never used it.

Comment: Tried with my personal email.  Didn't work.

Comment: Requires PHP 5.3+ or a non-Windows platform to work.

Comment: Didn't work for 5 of my email addresses (3 of them are Google Apps accounts, one of it is Hotmail and the last one is a regular GMail one). I am using PHP 5.3.3-7 on a Debian system.

Comment: That's because the 'checkdnsrr' function does not accept e-mail addresses!

`if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)),'MX'))`
`echo "valid e-mail address";`
`else`
`echo "invalid e-mail address";`

Answer (score 5):

`filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: Might be PHP-version-dependent, but may not fully support international domain names with Unicode characters (IDNs).

Answer (score 5):

```
function isemail($email) {
    return strlen($email) > 6 && preg_match("/^[\w\-\.]+@[\w\-\.]+(\.\w+)+$/", $email);
}
```

Comment: That is a very strict email regex

Comment: Is it really that simple?